# scope of variable in pipe

Tags: shell, pipe

The following shell scrip will check the disk space and change the variable `diskfull` to `1` if the usage is more than 10%
The last echo always shows `0` 
I tried the `global diskfull=1` in the if clause but it did not work.
How do I change the variable to `1` if the disk consumed is more than 10%?

```
#!/bin/sh
diskfull=0

ALERT=10
df -HP | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
  #echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
     diskfull=1
     exit
  fi
done

echo $diskfull
```

Comment: Are you sure that the body of the if statement is being executed?  More than likely the if is evaluating to false and the diskfull=1 line is never executed.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. What I did is that I exited the if clause with exit status 1 and then saved that to diskfull variable immediately after "done". This workaround seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pipes the shell seems to use sub-shells to do the work. As `$diskfull` is not known to these sub-shells the value is never changed.

See:
https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/0a66ba5e37c5d1746d8bc814b37d6e1d

I modified your script as follows. It works for me and should work on your system too.

```
#!/bin/sh
diskfull=0

ALERT=10
stats=`df -HP | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none|udev' | awk '{ print $5 "_" $1 }'`
for output in $stats
do
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | sed s/.*_// )
  #echo $partition -  $usep
  if [ $usep -le $ALERT ]; then
     diskfull=1
     break
  fi
done
echo $diskfull
```

Comment: dead site link!

Comment: Changed the dead link to a new site with similar content

Comment: Oops - "Well, this is awkward. The site you're looking for is not here." - Dreamhost ;)

Comment: Sorry. Just changed the text, but not the link. Now it should be working

Answer (score 6):

This is a side-effect of using `while` in a pipeline.  There are two workarounds:

1) put the `while` loop and all the variables it uses in a separate scope as demonstrated by levislevis86

```
some | complicated | pipeline | {
    while read line; do
        foo=$( some calculation )
    done
    do_something_with $foo
}
# $foo not available here
```

2) if your shell allows it, use **process substitution** and you can redirect the output of your pipeline to the input of the while loop

```
while read line; do
    foo=$( some calculation )}
done < <(some | complicated | pipeline)
do_something_with $foo
```

Comment: You may want to try [`set +o posix`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) before 2). Also look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Answer (score 1):

@OP, use an outer brace or ()

```
count=0
max=10
diskfull=0
df -HP | { while read disk b c d used e
do    
    if [ "$count" -gt 1 ];then
        used=${used%?}
        if [ "$used" -gt "$max" ];then
            echo "overload: $disk, used: $used%"
            diskfull=1
        fi
    fi
    count=$(( count+1 ))
done 
echo "diskfull: $diskfull" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not be getting to the `diskfull=1` line, because if you were, you would get no output at all-- the following `exit` line would exit the script.

I don't know why this isn't working, but note that awk can handle the rest of the work:

```
diskfull=$(df -HP | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk 'BEGIN { x = 0 } { if ($5 + 0 >= '$ALERT') { x = 1 } } END { print x }')
```

This way you don't need the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way with gawk(no need to use grep). for alerts you can send email to root.

```
threshold=10
df -HP | awk -v t="$threshold" -v msg="" 'NR>1 && $5+0 > t{ 
    msg=msg $1" is "$5"\n"
}END{print msg}' | mail root
```

or check whether there is "msg" or not first

```
threshold=10
result=$(df -HP | awk -v t="$threshold" -v msg="" 'NR>1 && $5+0 > t{ 
    msg=msg $1" is "$5"\n"
}END{print msg}')
if [ -n "$result" ];then
  echo "Overload"
  echo "$result" | mail root

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
```

it's not necessary to use `cut`. You can do this:

```
usep=$(echo $output | awk -F% '{ print $1}' )
```

Comment: using gawk, you can use $5+0 to change the field to integer. The % is "automatically gone". (for lack of better word)

Answer (score 0):

To deal with variable scope problem in bash loop, one can save the variable in a temporary file and later `cat` it to variable. It's not the smartest and efficient solution but It's easy to read and think.

If someone want to try something different than Glenn's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1790288/13286624), it can try this:

```
some | complicated | pipeline | {
while read line; do
    foo=$( some calculation )
done
do_something_with $foo

echo $foo > foo.tmp
}

# $foo not available here
foo=$(cat foo.tmp)
# $foo available here. do anything with it
rm foo.tmp
```

Please note, It's only valid if you have permission to create a file (or specify the absolute path to directory where you have permission)