# Linux shell bug? Variable assignment in pipe does not work

Tags: linux, shell

How come FILE_FOUND is 0 at the end of this bugger :

```
FILE_FOUND=0

touch /tmp/$$.txt

ls -1 /tmp/$$.* 2>/dev/null | while read item; do
    FILE_FOUND=1
    echo "FILE_FOUND = $FILE_FOUND"
done

echo "FILE_FOUND = $FILE_FOUND"

rm -f /tmp/$$.txt 2>/dev/null
```

??!!

On Unix FILE_FOUND stays at 1 (as it should), but on Linux (RedHat, Cygwin, ..) it jumps back to 0!!

Is it a Linux shell feature, not a bug? :)

Please help.

Comment: Which Linux shell are you using?  There are lots of them, each with their own "features".

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789750/global-scope-of-variable

Comment: Note that the `-1` option to `ls` is not required in a pipeline.

Comment: Answering a comment to @pixelbeat's answer: To mark the accepted answer, click on the outline 'tick' or 'check mark' symbol under the answer you think is correct/best.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I clicked the tick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

common issue which is caused because you're piping into the while, which is therefore run in a subshell, which can't pass environment variables back to its parent. I'm guessing that "unix" is different in this regard as you're running a different shell there (ksh?)

piping to the while loop may not be required. could you use this idiom instead?

```
for item in /tmp/$$.*; do
    ....
done
```

If you must use a subshell, then you'll have to do something external to the processes like:

```
touch /tmp/file_found
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  If there was a '(' ... ')' around the while you'd definitely be correct.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 - "The reason for this surprising behaviour is that a while/for/until loop runs in a SubShell when it's part of a pipeline." and "Different shells behave differently when using redirection or pipes with a loop"

Comment: would `export FILE_FOUND=1` help?

Comment: no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell

Answer (score 3):

This is a "feature" of the "bash" shell.  The "bash" manual entry states this clearly:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

The same construct executed with the Korn shell ("ksh") runs the "while" in the same process (not in a subshell) and hence gives the expected answer.  So I checked the spec.

The [POSIX shell specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02) is not crystal clear on this, but its does not say anything about changing the "shell execution environment", so I think that the UNIX / Korn shell implementations are compliant and the Bourne Again shell implementation is not.  But then, "bash" does not claim to be POSIX compliant!

Comment: it took me a while to spot the difference.

Comment: I think this is a typo in the question. Bash would not even execute the file without the "do".

Comment: @roe - you are correct.  I think this is really a bash "feature", but I'm still researching.

Comment: @Stephen C: that might be, however, it wouldn't "jump back to 0" on linux, because that line would never be executed, so it's just a typo in the question (o is right next to 0 on the keyboard).

Comment: @roe - actually, it WOULD jump back, because the variable is set and displayed (the first time) in the subshell.  That's what the quoted sentence above means!!

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned, but since you're piping into the while, the entire while-loop is run in a subshell. I'm not exactly sure which shell you're using on 'Unix', which I suppose means Solaris, but bash should behave consistenly regardless of platform.

To solve this problem, you can do a lot of things, the most common is to examin the result of the while loop somehow, like so

```
result=`mycommand 2>/dev/null | while read item; do echo "FILE_FOUND"; done`
```

and look for data in `$result`. Another common approach is to have the while loop produce valid variable assignments, and eval it directly.

```
eval `mycommand | while read item; do echo "FILE_FOUND=1"; done`
```

which will be evaluated by your 'current' shell to assign the given variables.

I'm assuming you don't want to just iterate over files, in which case you should be doing

```
for item in /tmp/$$.*; do
  # whatever you want to do
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, it's the extra shell you're creating by using the pipe notation.  Try this:

```
while read item; do
    FILE_FOUND=1
    echo "FILE_FOUND = $FILE_FOUND"
done < <(ls -1 /tmp/$$.* 2>/dev/null)
```

In this version, the `while` loop is in your script's shell, while the `ls` is a new shell (the opposite of what your script is doing).

Comment: Assuming that the user's shell understands **process substitution** (which is likely on linux)

Comment: did you actually try this? it feels like bash will put the while loop in a subshell to get the piping correct here as well.

Answer (score 0):

another way , bring the result back,

```
FILE_FOUND=0
result=$(echo "something" | while read item; do
    FILE_FOUND=1
    echo "$FILE_FOUND"

done )
echo "FILE_FOUND outside while = $result"
```

Comment: Nope: you need *all* references to `$FILE_FOUND` *inside* the braces.

Answer (score -2):

Ummmm... `ls -1` not `l` is on your script?