# Shell - Variable loses value after loop

Tags: shell, loops

I'm trying to count the occurrence of a word in a file which contains one word per line (using egrep was forbidden). I managed to find a solution, however I've stumbled upon a pretty strange thing, which I'd like some explanation as to why it happens like this.

My "count" variable has value of 0 after the loop, but it gets incremented correctly during the loop.

Here's my code:

```
for var in "$@" 
do
    count=0
    cat $1 | while read line ; do
        if [ $line = $var ]; then
            count=$((count + 1))
            echo "$var found $count times"
        fi
    done    
    echo $count
done
```

My output is:

```
yes found 0 times
yes found 1 times
yes found 2 times
0 - This is from the echo $count, which I find it very odd to be zero, since it got incremented to 3 during the loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you piped a new sub shell was spawned and count is being modified in that shell not your current one. It seems like other people are having this issue too. I came across this solution from another [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789750/scope-of-variable-in-pipe). I hope this helps!