# Variable loses value after recursion within while loop

Tags: linux, loops, shell

I've got a build pipeline that creates "packages" for my linux system, that I can then install on my system. How this works is that I have a bunch of folders that have a script to build the software, and a folder called deps with symlinks to other software folders that are required to be built beforehand.

Here is a visual of the hierarchy:

```
package1
    deps
        package2 -> sources/package2
    SCRIPT
package2
    deps
        package3 -> sources/package3
    SCRIPT
package3
    deps
    SCRIPT
```

The script is intended to go into each package folder, resolve all the dependencies by then traversing them and building if necessary, then returning back to build. I tried to create a recursive function to do such that.

```bash
build() {
    DEPENDS=()

    while read -r DEPENDENCY; do
        if [ -n "$DEPENDENCY" ]; then
            [ -f "$DEPENDENCY"/builtpkg ] || build "$DEPENDENCY" # Issue happens here, commenting this out makes $DEPENDENCY not lose its value
            DEPENDS=("-include $DEPENDENCY/builtpkg")
        fi
    done <<< "$(find $1/deps -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec readlink {} \;)"

    . "$DEPENDENCY/SCRIPT" # calls actual build logic
}

while read -r PACKAGE; do
    build "$PACKAGE"
done <<< "$(find "$PWD/sources" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

Explanation of code (I will attach a small, reproducible code as well that you may run on your systems and see the issue in action):

- Iterates through all the sources and calls `build()` on them
- Within `build()`, iterate on all symlinks in the `deps`, if they aren't already built build them via `build()`, otherwise skip this step
- Build by executing the provided build script.

For some reason, at the point where I call the `build()` in the while loop, the next time I use the variable `$DEPENDENCY`, the value goes missing, in that it becomes an empty string, for no apparent reason at all.

Since this code is too big and fluffy, I've attached a small reproducible script (it runs on /tmp and makes a directory called test).

```bash
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test

# Make a faux fs-heirarchy to test my function in
prep() {
    mkdir -p pkg1/deps
    mkdir -p pkg2/deps
    mkdir -p pkg3/deps
    mkdir -p pkg4/deps
    mkdir -p pkg5/deps

    ln -s pkg2 pkg1/deps/pkg2
    ln -s pkg3 pkg1/deps/pkg3
    ln -s pkg4 pkg1/deps/pkg4
}

prep

func() {
    echo "in: $1"
    while read -r DEPENDENCY; do
        # non-empty means theres a dependency to build
        if [ -n "$DEPENDENCY" ]; then
            echo "requires: $DEPENDENCY"
            [ -f "$DEPENDENCY"/built ] || func "$DEPENDENCY" # either dependency exists, or we recursively build
            echo ":: $DEPENDENCY" # string is empty here
        fi
    done < <(find "$1/deps" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec readlink {} \;)

    # touch $1/built # mimicking building
}

while read -r DIRECTORY; do
    func "$DIRECTORY"
done <<< "$(find "$PWD" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)"
```

For some reason, when I run this code on my system, I get:

```
$ ./test.sh
in: /tmp/test/pkg5
in: /tmp/test/pkg4
in: /tmp/test/pkg3
in: /tmp/test/pkg2
in: /tmp/test/pkg1
requires: pkg4
in pkg4:
::
requires: pkg3
in: pkg3
::
requires: pkg2
in: pkg2
::
```

What I expected was `::` would be replaced with `:: pkg4` or `:: pkg3`, but instead it prints absolutely nothing. Confusingly enough, when I comment out the `[ -f ... ] || func "$DEPENDENCY"`, `::` will always have a value, so it wont go missing. I'm very confused as to why.

I read through some stackoverflow posts, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667509/shell-variables-set-inside-while-loop-not-visible-outside-of-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600489/shell-variable-loses-value-after-loop), both recommending not to pipe but using process substitution, but this doesn't apply since I am using process substitution via `<<<`.

What's going on? I'm losing my variable and its breaking my script further down because I need to attach them into a `DEPENDS=()` array, which it can't if the variable goes empty.