# Unable to get final count of S3 objects with bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-s3

I am trying to get count of specific file extension from S3 bucket using `AWS CLI` but not sure why final count is not showing. I can see the count inside the while loop but not outside. Please help me.

Code:

```
function countObjects(){
    objectCounts=0
    aws s3 ls s3://"$BucketName" --recursive --human-readable  --summarize | grep ".pdf" | while read -r line; do
        echo "FILE NAME: $line"
        if [ "$line" == None ]; then
            echo "File format is different"
        else
            objectCounts=$(expr $objectCounts + 1)
            echo "Count is $objectCounts"
        fi  
    done
    echo "Final Txt Object Counts: $objectCounts"
} 
countObjects
```

I tried to add while loop condition but still not showing.

Comment: Bash pipelines are executed in a sub-shell, you need to [propagate the value back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727116).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scope of variable in pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789750/scope-of-variable-in-pipe)

Comment: Instead of that while loop you could just do `grep -vc None`